# Sidebar limiting to 10 posts?

Tags: posts, wp-query, sidebar, categories

I have the following code inside my single.php page:

**UPDATED CODE**

```
 <?php if (have_posts()) : the_post();
     $post_id = get_the_ID();

 if ( is_single() ) {
         $cats =  get_the_category();
         $cat = $cats[0];
 } else {
         // category archives
         $cat = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
 }

 $cat_id = $cat->cat_ID;
 $cat_name = $cat->name;
 $cat_slug = $cat->slug;
?>
<?php query_posts('cat='.$cat_id); ?>
   <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>    
     <div id="sidebar">
       <h3><?php echo get_cat_name($cat_id); $theCount = 0; ?></h3>
         <ul class="info-list">
           <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); $theCount += 1; echo 'debug>' . $theCount; ?>
             <li <?php if ($post_id == get_the_ID()) {echo 'class="active"';} ?>>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                  <span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                </a>
             </li>
           <?php endwhile; ?>
         </ul>
     </div>
   <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Problem being is that it only seems to grab the last 10 posts in that category where i know i have 16 posts for that sidebar to display.

Where in the code could i find where its limiting the return values??

**UPDATE**

```
 <?php if (have_posts()) : the_post();
                            $post_id = get_the_ID();

            if ( is_single() ) {
                    $cats =  get_the_category();
                    $cat = $cats[0];
            } else {
                // category archives
                    $cat = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
            }

            $cat_id = $cat->cat_ID;
            $cat_name = $cat->name;
            $cat_slug = $cat->slug;


                    $cat_query_args = array(
// Include posts from category with ID $cat_id
'cat' => $cat_id,
// Include all posts
'posts_per_page' => -1
);

 $cat_query = new WP_Query( $cat_query_args );


 if ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) 

 ?>
 <div id="sidebar">
    <h3><?php echo get_cat_name($cat_id); $theCount = 0; ?></h3>
    <ul class="info-list">

    <?php
    while $cat_query->have_posts() : $cat_query->the_post();

        $theCount += 1; echo 'debug>' . $theCount; 
        ?>
        <li <?php if ($post_id == get_the_ID()) {echo 'class="active"';} ?>>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
            </a>
        </li>
       <?php

endwhile; 
?>

     </ul>
 </div>
<?php

 endif;

 ?>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using **`query_posts()`**, when you need to be using [**`WP_Query()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). To display all posts (by ignoring pagination, use the [`posts_per_page` parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters):

```
$cat_query_args = array(
    // Include posts from category with ID $cat_id
    'cat' => $cat_id,
    // Include all posts
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$cat_query = new WP_Query( $cat_query_args );

if ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) : 

     ?>
     <div id="sidebar">
        <h3><?php echo get_cat_name($cat_id); $theCount = 0; ?></h3>
        <ul class="info-list">

        <?php
        while ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) : $cat_query->the_post();

            $theCount += 1; echo 'debug>' . $theCount; 
            ?>
            <li <?php if ($post_id == get_the_ID()) {echo 'class="active"';} ?>>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                </a>
            </li>
           <?php

    endwhile; 
    ?>

         </ul>
     </div>
    <?php

endif;

// Be kind; rewind
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help again, Chip. However, it does not seem to load the page now since i added that code over my old code.

Comment: I've also updated my code with how i am getting the cat_id.

Comment: Please note: code is example/proof-of-concept only, and is not necessarily intended to be copy-and-paste-ready. If the page stopped loading, there's probably a syntax error somewhere causing a fatal error.

Comment: Can you use my code mixed with your code as it should be? I can not seem to get it working when i splice them together?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to. The keys are to replace `query_posts()` with `WP_Query()`, to include the `posts_per_page` parameter, and to instantiate the loop properly.

Comment: I'm getting errors on **while $cat_query->have_posts() : $cat_query->the_post();** and on **endwhile;**

Comment: Updated my OP to show how i used your code.

Comment: There were syntax errors. See updated code, with respect to `if ( $cat_query->have_posts() )` and `while ( $cat_query->have_posts() )`. The former was missing a closing parenthesis, and the latter was not wrapped in parentheses.

Comment: Ah i corrected that just as you updated your post :) Thanks for the help, Chip!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) only when you are intentionally messing with the main query, which should be almost never.

Use [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) or or create a new [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) object instead.

```
$my_posts = get_posts(
    'cat='.$cat_id, 
    'posts_per_page=50'
);
```

If your `$cat_id` is correct, that should work. Then loop over it like this ([from the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Access_all_post_data)):

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 3 );
$lastposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach($lastposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Or use `WP_Query` like ([also from the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Usage)):

```
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;
```

Comment: I've updated my OP code with how i am getting the cat_id.

Comment: No. **Never** use `query_posts()`, even if messing with the main query. Filter `pre_get_posts` instead.

Comment: That looks right but I don't know if your actually getting the value you want. Only you know that.

Answer (score -1):

WP codex is your best friend:

From `query_posts` [codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts):

> For example, on the homepage, you would normally see the latest 10 posts. If you want to show only 5 posts (and don't care about pagination), you can use query_posts() like so:
>
> ```
> query_posts( 'posts_per_page=5' );
> ```

Comment: Do not use `query_posts()`, *especially* not for secondary queries.

Comment: That doesnt seem to be working? **<?php query_posts('cat='.$cat_id, 'posts_per_page=50'); ?>**

Comment: @ChipBennett the original question had no reference to or suggestion that this was a secondary query, and that information is clearly stated in the first paragraph of the link provided.

Comment: First, the question *inherently* involves a secondary loop, by virtue of being a *sidebar* loop. Regardless, using `query_posts()` is **always** `_doing_it_wrong()`, and should **never** be recommended. Also, any relevant information should not be left to source material via links, but should be included in the answer itself.